# What would be the correct Razor syntax that contains conditional logic

Tags: c#, razor

I want to show 3 items per row in a razor file. I have to add *div class="row"* and closing tag at every 3 items. Below is my best attempt:

```
@{

  int maxInRow = 3;
  int counter = 1;

  <div class="main">

  @foreach(var item in allItems)
  {

    if(counter == 1)
    {
        <div class="row">
    }

    <div class="article">Here is the article.</div>

    @{counter++;}
    if(counter == maxInRow)
    {
        counter = 1;
        </div>
    }

  </div>
}
```

What would be the correct Razor syntax?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement using below code:

```
@{
   <div class="main">
       @for (int i = 0; i < allItems.Count; i += 3)
       {
          <div class="row">
              @for (int j = i; j < i + 3 && j < allItems.Count; j++)
              {
                <div class="article">Here is the article. @allItems[j]</div>
              }
          </div>
        }
   </div>            
  }
```

Comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: I need i and J as counters so I've choosen this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can make this really simple using LINQ and grouping

```
var itemsInGroupsOf3 = allItems.Select((item, i) => new { Index = i, Item = item })
                               .GroupBy(i => i.Index / 3);

foreach(var group in itemsInGroupsOf3)
{
    var groupItems = group.Select(g => g.Item);

    <div class="row">
        @foreach(var item in groupItems)
        {
            <div class="article">Here is the article.</div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Much better approach than conditional HTML (which is error prone and hard to maintain).